# How to estimate the order of magnitude of the solution to a closest vector problem?

Tags: approximation, integer-lattices

Given a closest vector problem (CVP):

> Let $\mathbf{B}=[\mathbf{b}_1, \mathbf{b}_2, \dots, \mathbf{b}_n]$ be the basis matrix of the lattice $\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{B})=\{\mathbf{Bx}|\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{Z}^n\}$. Find $\mathbf{b} \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbf{B})$ such that the distance to the target vector $\mathbf{t}$ $$||\mathbf{b} - \mathbf{t}||$$ is minimized.

How can we estimate the order of magnitude of $$\min_{\mathbf{b} \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbf{B})} ||\mathbf{b} - \mathbf{t}||$$?

If we are given concrete numbers for the CVP, I know we can just run Babai's Nearest Plane algorithm on the problem and use the obtained solution to bound the desired quantity. However, I would like a solution that is more symbolic, in terms of $\mathbf{B}$ and $\mathbf{t}$.

Specifically, I am working with problems of the form $$\mathbf{B}=\begin{pmatrix}
a_1       & 0          & \cdots & 0 \\
0          & a_2       & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots     & \vdots     & \ddots & \vdots \\
0          & 0          & \cdots & a_n \\
b_1 & b_2 & \cdots & b_n
\end{pmatrix}, \, \mathbf{t} = \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ c \\
\end{pmatrix}$$, if this makes any difference.